# Using different TLS record versions in the same TCP connection

Tags: security, ssl

TLS record looks like:

```
struct {
   ContentType type;
   ProtocolVersion version;
   uint16 length;
   opaque fragment[TLSPlaintext.length];
} TLSPlaintext;
```

Is it legal to use different TLS record version in the same TCP connection
(e.g. ClientHello version 3.2 (TLS 1.0) and ServerHello 3.2 (TLS 1.1))?

What RFC (e.g. in [TLS 1.0 RFC 2246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt)) says about it?

Thanks

Comment: @Yahia Is it answer/clue? :) Indeed I searched through RFC, but worthless. Maybe I'm missing something. This is not that I'm going to mix record versions intentionally, just my application is between client and server and I want to know to what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

It's semantically unsound to try to use two versions of a protocol in one connection. The TLS "record version" isn't just about the record itself, but the grammar of many records put together, such as their order or length, and going in with the wrong expectations can leave you stranded in the stream not knowing where the next record even starts.

TCP connections are cheap. If you need to negotiate a new connection, it's better to do so instead of trying to force a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: There're two versions - one in record header, second is ssl negotiated version by means of ClientHello/ServerHello messages. These version may be different (e.g. see paragraph E. " Backward Compatibility With SSL" in TLS 1.0 RFC 2246). My question is regarding  first one version 0 version in record header.

Comment: And in the "Backward Compatibility With SSL" section, it explains again how you should always negotiate the highest version of the specification your client understands, making no mention of using two versions at the same time - because using two versions at a time would be nonsense.